# How to sort with an array of ids in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of `User` documents, I also have an array of User `_id`s, I know I can find all `User`s by during a `_id: {$in: user_ids}`, but I want to sort the whole collection with the documents in the array first and the rest following, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/JZrBYDybETV

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$userIds" }, // break into individual documents
  { $sort: { "userIds": 1 } }, // sort them
  { $group: { "_id": "$_id", "userIds": { $push: "$userIds" } } } // join them back
])
```